# Check when CSS is reloaded using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following technique to reload some CSS in a page builder that I am working on:

1. Get reference to `<link>` targeting the CSS.
2. Get current timestamp via `Date.getTime()`.
3. Update the `href` attribute of that link to the CSS file + the timestamp as a parameter.

This works fine, but I am also using Masonry for the layout and I need to reload it once the CSS has reloaded - something I am finding surprisingly tricky. I assumed it to be as simple as:

```
$("link#compcss").on("load", function(){
    // Do masonry reload.    
});
```

But this is only triggering the first time it loads with the page. What is the correct way to know when the CSS has been reloaded?

Comment: I think you should replace the link tag with a new one and add onload handler to the new link tag which will call a function to reload masonry. You should provide relevant code where you update href attribute

Comment: @A.Wolff That appears to have a) worked and b) made the original process I had in place redundant. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try reload method

```
 $('#container').masonry( 'reload' );
```

REFERENCE

[RELOAD](http://desandro.github.io/masonry/docs/methods.html#reload)

Comment: That's not what I'm asking.